# The site degenerates on iPhone every couple of days

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I have a strange problem. Every few days the site loses functionality, I cannot post comments or flag, I cannot close or even view my inbox.

All the popups say that an error has occurred but never specify the error.

When I clear out the cookies it works again. However this sort of action destroys every other cookie that I might have wanted to keep on my iPhone (e.g. the mail logon) and it gets pretty annoying.

Does anyone else have that problem lately?

Comment: I have seen somewhat similar behavior with the mobile version of the site on Android handsets. In particular, the browser will freeze and the CPU will go into overdrive, using up the vast majority of available CPU cycles. Killing the browser process in the Task Manager seems to work, but you have to do this about every 2 to 4 times you open the site. If I were to suspect something, it would be that some part of the scripting was not getting handled correctly.

Comment: @cardinal: this is not the same problem.

Comment: I realize that, but it is similar. When this happens one cannot comment, flag, answer, etc. Also, one gets an error about MathJax not loading some fonts by default (or something). My intention was to provide another data point that might indicate that the mobile-site functionality should be looked at more closely.

Comment: Have you tried simply force-quitting the browser on the iPhone and restarting it?

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this and have no other reports of it.